# Reading through an array of characters and returning the char type accordingly

Tags: java

I am reading each character from a arraylist of char and trying to get the letters, digits and spaces separately.

The arraylist has:

```
[h, e, l, l, o,  , j, a,  , m, e, s,  , 2, 4, , h, o, w,  , a, r, e,  , y, o, 2, 2, u,]
```

I tried coding as below:

```
String name="";
for(int i=0;i<c.size();)
{
    if(Character.isLetter(c.get(i)))
    {
        //System.out.println("letter");
        while(c.get(i)!= 32)
        {
            name = "its a id";
            System.out.println(name);
            i++;
        }       
    }
    else if(Character.isDigit(c.get(i)))
    {
        // System.out.println("digit");
        name = "its a digit";
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    else if(c.get(i)>=0 && c.get(i)<=32)
    {
        name="its a space";  
        System.out.println(name);           
    }
}
```

But this is not working properly. I am going into infinite loop here. How can I increment the `i` value next to the space and again loop through these conditions? Basically I am trying to differentiate between identifiers, digits and spaces.

Comment: You increment i by incrementing i.

Comment: How can i get the tokens separately as hello,ja,mes,24,how,are,you22u

Comment: You do this thing called "programming".  Try it.

Answer (score 0):

That'd be pretty simple. Just state the `for` loop like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<c.size();i++)
```

You should also delete the `i++` in the first `if` clause.

---

There are other ways to loop through an `ArrayList`. You could loop by the iterator:

```
for (Iterator i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); Character ch = iterator.next();)
```

Then you refer to `ch` instead of `c.get(i)`.

You can use the special kind of `for` loop (please help me with my amnesia, what is this called):

```
for (Character ch : c)
```

Again, you must refer to `ch` instead of `c.get(i)`.

Comment: He also needs to remove the line "i++;" from the first if-statement.

Comment: @JohnZeringue I just put that.

Comment: but i want to get you22u as an identfier , if i loop through each character then when it comes to 2 it will go into isDigit condition

Comment: Ummm, the `i++` in the first `if` statement is in a `while` loop, so simply deleting it will produce an infinite loop.  The entire logic has to be reexamined, and in fact the requirements aren't completely clear.

Comment: adding i++ in each if else statements works.Actually i am tokenizing the input stream.

Comment: This is maybe just a personal thing, but... When I see a loop like `for (int i=0; i<c.size(); i++)`, I assume the loop will run `c.size()` times (barring `break`, `return`, etc.).  If there's any other logic inside the loop that also increments `i` or does anything else to modify `i`, I find it confusing and more difficult to read.  In cases like that my preference is to use a `while` instead of a `for`; then I know that I will need to look in the body of the loop to see how and when the index is modified.  Just my own style thing, I don't know if anyone else feels the same.